# AutoFixture as an Automocking container vs Automocking differences?

Tags: c#, .net, moq, autofixture, automocking

I started to use moq but from my understanding I always have to mock up all the methods that could be called even if I really do not care about them.

Sometimes it takes so long to mockup stuff you forget what you want to do. So I been looking at auto mocking but I am not sure what one I should use.

[AutoFixture as an auto-mocking container](http://blog.ploeh.dk/2010/08/19/AutoFixtureAsAnAutomockingContainer.aspx)

[Automocking](http://code.google.com/p/moq-contrib/wiki/Automocking)

I don't get how to use the first one at all. I sort of get the second one but never really tried it.

I am not sure if one is better than the other. The only thing I know is I am using AutoFixtures already what is a dependency of the first one.

So maybe in the long run it makes sense to go with the first one but like I said I can't find any basic tutorials on how to use it.

**Edit**

I am trying to follow "Nikos Baxevanis" examples but I am running into errors.

```
Failure: System.ArgumentException : A matching constructor for the given arguments was not found on the mocked type.
  ----> System.MissingMethodException : Constructor on type 'DatabaseProxyded46c36c8524889972231ef23659a72' not found.


var fixture = new Fixture().Customize(new AutoMoqCustomization());
        var fooMock = fixture.Freeze<Mock<IFoo>>();
       // fooMock.Setup(x => x.GetAccounts(It.IsAny<IUnitOfWork>()));
        var sut = fixture.CreateAnonymous<AdminService>();

        sut.Apply();
        fooMock.VerifyAll();
```

I think it is because of my petapoco unitOfWork property

```
PetaPoco.Database Db { get; }
```

Not sure if I got to mock this up somehow or what.

Comment: About the exception that you get, there is nothing wrong with the way you use AutoFixture and Auto-Mocking. I would be happy to help further if you can include in your question the source code for all the types used by the test.

Comment: Ya I been walking through the code and the problem is in my service layer method(the method I am trying to unit test). A call is made. Eventhough I have a unit of work that is an interface the property Db is not a interface and that is causing it to crash. I have to mock it out but the petapoco does not have an interface. So I to wrap it I guess

Answer (score 26, accepted):

While I have never used `moq-contrib Automocking`, I could probably provide some information on using [AutoFixture](https://github.com/autofixture/autofixture) as an auto-mocking container.

Currently there is support for Moq, Rhino Mocks, FakeItEasy, and NSubstitute. Just install the appropriate extension [AutoMoq](http://nuget.org/packages/AutoFixture.AutoMoq), [AutoRhinoMocks](http://nuget.org/packages/AutoFixture.AutoRhinoMocks), [AutoFakeItEasy](http://nuget.org/packages/AutoFixture.AutoFakeItEasy), and [AutoNSubstitute](http://nuget.org/packages/AutoFixture.AutoNSubstitute).

Once you have installed one of the extensions for Auto Mocking the *extra* call is:

```
var fixture = new Fixture()
    .Customize(new AutoMoqCustomization());
```

*(or if you are using Rhino Mocks)*

```
var fixture = new Fixture()
     .Customize(new AutoRhinoMockCustomization());
```

*(or if you are using FakeItEasy)*

```
var fixture = new Fixture()
     .Customize(new AutoFakeItEasyCustomization());
```

*(or if you are using NSubstitute)*

```
var fixture = new Fixture()
     .Customize(new AutoNSubstituteCustomization());
```

#### Example 1

```
public class MyController : IController
{
    public MyController(IFoo foo)
    {
    }
}

public interface IFoo
{
}
```

Here is how to use AutoFixture to create instances of `MyController` class:

```
var fixture = new Fixture()
    .Customize(new AutoMoqCustomization());

var sut = fixture.CreateAnonymous<MyController>();
```

Now, if you inspect the `sut` variable you will see the the `IFoo` is a mocked instance *(having a type name similar to Castle.Proxies.IFooProxy)*.

#### Example 2

This examples extends the previous one.

You can instruct AutoFixture to use your own, pre-configured, mocked instance:

```
var fooMock = fixture.Freeze<Mock<IFoo>>();
// At this point you may setup expectation(s) on the fooMock.

var sut = fixture.CreateAnonymous<MyController>();
// This instance now uses the already created fooMock.
// Verify any expectation(s).
```

---

That's basically it - but it can go further!

Below are the previous examples using AutoFixture [decleratively](http://blog.ploeh.dk/2010/10/08/AutoDataTheoriesWithAutoFixture.aspx) with the xUnit.net [extension](http://nuget.org/packages/AutoFixture.Xunit/).

#### Example 1

```
[Theory, AutoMoqData]
public void TestMethod(MyController sut)
{
    // Start using the sut instance directly.
}
```

#### Example 2

```
[Theory, AutoMoqData]
public void TestMethod([Frozen]Mock<IFoo> fooMock, MyController sut)
{
   // At this point you may setup expectation(s) on the fooMock.
   // The sut instance now uses the already created fooMock.
   // Verify any expectation(s).
}
```

> You may find more information on [this](http://nikosbaxevanis.com/2012/07/31/autofixture-xunit-net-and-auto-mocking/) blog post which contains links to everything related around AutoFixture, xUnit.net, and Auto Mocking.

Hope that helps.

Comment: What is Freeze? I don't get it. Your 2nd example is showing how to mockup everything but if you want to start passing in your own stuff then that is what you do?

Comment: You may `Freeze` an instance of a type so that when AutoFixture needs to create an instance of the same type it will _reuse_ the already created one. You may find more information about this feature [here](http://blog.ploeh.dk/2010/03/17/AutoFixtureFreeze.aspx).

Comment: Keep in mind that `Freeze` is needed only if you need to set an expectation to a mocked instance which is a dependency of the requested type. (Of course, you may have to freeze more than one type instances depending on the scenario.)

Comment: Hmm ok, Got to play around with it but my undestanding of is correct right? That these will make a fake mockup of all methods(that have an interfaces) right? Then the methods you care about can then go further and setup them up with moq setup function? I also don't 100% get what is going on here var fooMock = fixture.Freeze<Mock<IFoo>>(); Why did you go out of your way to mock IFoo where in the 1st example you did not.

Comment: On `Example 1` we don't really care to setup an expectation on the `IFoo` mock. We just go ahead and ask AutoFixture to create an instance of the `MyController` type. This will automatically inject a mocked instance of `IFoo` type. On `Example 2`, we *do* want to setup and expectation so we manually create a mocked instance and we _Freeze_ it - telling AutoFixture to _reuse_ the already created instance when requesting the `MyController` type. (If we don't do that, the expectation would fail since the `MyController` is going to use another instance - not the one that we setup the expectation.)

Comment: Would it be bad to just create the fixture in the constructor and then use it through all the tests?

Comment: @ Nikos Baxevanis - Been trying to get your code examples to work in my project but I keep getting an error. See my OP.

Comment: In this particular scenario, I would strongly suggest to let AutoFixture handle the object creation including any of the dependencies. Your unit tests are more robust that way - e.g. if for some reason you modify the constructor(s) there are less chances for compile time erros.

Comment: I been playing around with your examples and I wanted to confirm that order seems to matter? I tried making the controller object first then the IFooMock and my unit tests failed(since I used moq verify and said the method should only be called once). I am thinking it first made the automock then it made the mock that I told it to make thus calling each method twice?

Comment: Yes, that is expected because first you requested the `MyController` type (so AutoFixture supplied an auto-mocked instance for the `IFoo` dependency) and after you created a _new_ mock of `IFoo` (which is a different instance of the one that was passed in the `MyController`). When you need to set an expectation on a mock _Freeze_ it _before_ you request a type that depends on the mocked object. That way, AutoFixture will _reuse_ the already created mock and the expectation will succeed.