# fill an object instance via AutoFixture, but not by a generic but by type

Tags: autofixture

Is it possible to either create an object by type, for example:

```
Type typeToCreate = typeof(TestModel);
Fixture fixture = new Fixture();
var item = fixture.Create(typeToCreate)
```

Or something where I can pass an already created object and it is filled, for example:

```
fixture.Fill(myAlreadyCreatedObject);
```

I could only manage to create items by generics, like `fixture.Create<MyType>()`.  This works fine, but generics sometimes limit you if the type is determined at runtime.

Comment: Yes, that's possible. You may want to look at this [answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/18954051/467754).

Comment: Thanks for pointing that out, works perfect! If you post it as answer I can accept it, as it is the answer.

Comment: @NikosBaxevanis If you add the answer it'd be nice, because it means that the question would no longer look unanswered in list views.

Comment: @MarkSeemann Good point. Done.

Comment: What about filling an existing object without creating a new one?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, that's possible with AutoFixture.

You may want to look at this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/18954051/467754) which shows an example of it.